# How to get individual datagrid cell values?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to obtain cell values from a datagrid. Assuming the datagrid has 4 columns and 3 rows, how do I go about obtaining the cell value of column 1, row 1?

I have tried using:

```
var column1row1: String = datagrid2.getItemAt (column1row1).Support_Type;
```

which gives me the values of column 1, and I do not know how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`getItemAt()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/SelectableList.html#getItemAt()) will just give you the row (as an `Object`) at the used index ( the index `1` will select the second row ), then to get the data, you can select the column name, like this :

```
// supposed that the 2nd column (with index 1) is called 'email'
// and we are looking for the value of the cell[1, 1] (2nd row, 2nd col)

trace(data_grid.getItemAt(1).email);    
// gives for example : email@example.com
```

You can also use [`DataGrid.getCellRendererAt()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html#getCellRendererAt()) which will return an [`CellRenderer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/listClasses/CellRenderer.html) object then you can use its [`listData`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/listClasses/CellRenderer.html#listData) property to get the desired value :

```
trace(data_grid.getCellRendererAt(1, 1).listData.label);    
// gives for example : email@example.com
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: That really helped! Thanks a lot!